# Erro ao iniciar o aplicativo com react-native run-android

Tags: react-native, path

Estou tentando inciar com react-native fiz a instalação conforme esse link https://docs.rocketseat.dev/ambiente-react-native/android/linux porém quando rodo o comando `react-native run-android` com o aplicativo padrão  ele informa o erro abaixo

```
   info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
    Jetifier found 855 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
    info Starting JS server...
    info Installing the app...

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    > The SDK directory '/home/raellopes/raellopes/Android/Sdk' does not exist.

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 1s

    error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
    Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    > The SDK directory '/home/raellopes/raellopes/Android/Sdk' does not exist.

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 1s

        at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
        at execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
        at runOnAllDevices (/home/raellopes/Área de Trabalho/pessoal/projeto/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:75:39)
        at buildAndRun (/home/raellopes/Área de Trabalho/pessoal/projeto/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:169:41)
        at then.result (/home/raellopes/Área de Trabalho/pessoal/projeto/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:135:12)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: Você conecta o seu emulador com adb connect?

Comment: Sim ,e faz a conexão corretamente,porém quando dou o react-native run-android ele apresenta esse erro

Comment: Pelo erro ele não consegue encontrar sua pasta Android/Sdk

Comment: O que devo fazer?quero começar a estudar react-native

Comment: Você criou sua pasta Android/Sdk na sua home? Depois baixou o android studio  e colou la dentro?

Comment: Recomendo seguir o próprio tutorial do react native: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

Comment: Não,deixei na area de trabalho

Comment: no emulador você apontou para essa pasta?

Comment: Sim,conseguir seguindo o link que voce passou com o expo,bem mais pratico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de instalar o android studio conforme o passo a passo do [Getting Started do React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started), vá no aplicativo Android Studio > Preferences e procure por "sdk".

Baixe a versão do SDK conforme recomendado [na página do React](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started), assim como as ferramentas (SDK-Tools).

Agora, na raiz da pasta android, dentro do seu projeto React Native, crie um arquivo "local.properties", e insira nele o diretório de instalação do SDK do android.

Um exemplo do diretório "local.properties" no MacOS:

```
sdk.dir = /Users/"seu_usuario"/Library/Android/sdk
```

Isso deve funcionar, espero que tenha esclarecido!

Comment: Maravilha amigo, deu certo sim, muito obrigado.